# What are some 3rd party rendering engines available for Blender?

Tags: rendering, external-applications

What are some 3rd party rendering engines available for Blender? I am using the internal blender render and I keep hearing in tutorials (blenderguru) that it is better to use an external render engine...

Comment: Integrated Octane render . Vray Exporter.

Comment: You can find a list of free rendering engines here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15137226/2044940. There should be blender addons for all 5 of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few open source engines which come to mind immediately:

- [Luxrender](http://www.luxrender.net/)
- [Yafaray](http://www.yafaray.org/)
- [TheBounty](https://www.thebountyrenderer.org/), a fork of YafaRay
- [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/) ([exporter](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/POV-Ray))
- [Aqsis](http://aqsis.org/)
- [Jot](http://jot.cs.princeton.edu/) ([exporter](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Jot_Exporter_for_Blender))
- [Mitsuba](https://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/) implement biased and unbiased rendering techniques ([Exporter](https://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/repos/exporters/mitsuba-blender/))

Some non-open source engines:

- [Octane](http://render.otoy.com/index.php), fast GPU renderer integrated into blender (Commercial)
- [Vray](http://www.chaosgroup.com/en/2/vray_blender.html), production proven render engine. (Commercial)

---

Also see the answer on the [resources post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15363/599) for even more.