# Is Mental Ray available for Blender?

Tags: rendering

Is Mental Ray available for Blender? Are there any other production quality render options?

Comment: read this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15363/1853

Comment: also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/what-are-some-3rd-party-rendering-engines-available-for-blender

Comment: Mental ray is an old engine and wasn't updated since 3-4 years. For what reason you'd like to use it?

Comment: @poor I'm coming from Maya and it was the standard to use it there (other than Renderman, and a few other paid options). What is currently used most for Blender for production quality? Thanks guys! :D

Comment: @Animatoring Cycles

Comment: Depending on your hardware, you can go with Vray or Octane, since Arnold isn't supported...